# System.out.println doesn't work - JBoss

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I'm deploying my application on a JBOSS server v7.1 and untill yesterday everything works ok.

But today, I can't see `System.out.println()` messages in the console and neither in the log of the server.

I don't know how to debug this or search for a solution.

-->A cause [maybe] : I've deleted a maven project this morning from my eclipse.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: You should not be using System.out.println; you should be using a logger like log4j.

Comment: it's just for testing and it was working fine.

Comment: Shouldn't do it for testing either.  Bad habit.  If it "was working", then you changed something to break it.  Put it back.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: even with log4j I got nothing

Comment: My problem is clear, I don't know how to debug my problem and that's what I'm seeking

Comment: Can you see any log on console?

Answer (score 0):

***This was the solution :***

The maven project that've deleted was on JDK 8 and my current project is JDK 7, so when I've deleted it somehow it changed the JDK for the other project.

That provoked JBOSS to update only web pages and not JAVA classes and that's why I didn't get any new message.

**-->Before downgrading a question, at least take a time to undrestand and provide a valid reason, because in my case I did give you the clue !**